# is it a good idea to place global property file in USER_HOME environment variable

Tags: java, configuration

I am using a third party API, which loads the global property file from environment variable using following code

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

or

```
System.getenv(XYZ_HOME_VAR_NAME);
```

As I am using Jenkins CI, so I have to create the folder inside user_home of the system.

I am not sure if this is a bad coding practice.

Please suggest if this is correct...

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad practice as such, but you may find the preferences API easier to use.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html

Comment: my only concern is that when I am building the builds over Jenkins, the test cases will pick the config. file from user.home. This is fine right?

Comment: Do the tests need different configurations or modify the file? If they do you probably should add an option to use a specific file instead of the default to keep the tests from stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: No. Test cases loads the same global config. file. As the logic of loading config. resides inside src/main/java/util/GlobalConfiguration.java.